# secure endpoint present within keycloak itself

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak, keycloak-services, keycloak-rest-api

I have an endpoint such as below within keycloak itself,which is a springboot one,

```js
package com.manh.cp.keycloak.BruteForce;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController {

    @GetMapping("/userBruteForce")
    public List<User> getUserData() {
        List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
        users.add(new User("Dr. Dre", 3, "2023-09-28"));
        users.add(new User("Eminem", 3, "2023-09-28"));
        users.add(new User("Tupac", 3, "2023-09-28"));
        users.add(new User("Drake", 3, "2023-09-28"));
        return users;
    }

    static class User {
        private String user;
        private int failedAttempts;
        private String lockDate;

        public User(String user, int failedAttempts, String lockDate) {
            this.user = user;
            this.failedAttempts = failedAttempts;
            this.lockDate = lockDate;
        }

        public String getUser() {
            return user;
        }

        public int getFailedAttempts() {
            return failedAttempts;
        }

        public String getLockDate() {
            return lockDate;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to protect the endpoint such that only a valid token from keycloak-admin-client or any other client is only granted access to it. I am using the below code to generate the token and display the data from the endpoint in the keycloak-admin-console. Even though I am able to display the data, I want to secure the endpoint within the keycloak code itself. Any idea on how to do so ? thanks in advance.

```js
   useEffect(() => {
const fetchData = async () => {
  try {
    const kcAdminClient = new KcAdminClient();

    // Authenticate with Keycloak using username/password
    await kcAdminClient.auth({
      username: "admin",
      password: "admin",
      grantType: "password",
      clientId: "admin-cli",
    });

    const accessToken = await kcAdminClient.getAccessToken();

    const response = await Axios.get<Row[]>(
      "https://localhost:10191/api/userBruteForce",

      {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
      }
    );
    setFetchedLockedUsersData(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  }
};

fetchData();
  }, []);
```